# Python3: Enter regex pattern from command line

Tags: python, regex, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a script searching for, say, a word + "(". I'd use:

```
pattern = re.compile( "anyword\(" )
```

But I want to have users enter the pattern string from the command
line (Windows 10).

```
argp = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argp.add_argument("-p", metavar="pattern", type=str,
                 , help="regex pattern")
args= argp.parse_args()
pattern = re.compile( args.p )
```

But it fails to handle `anyword\(` properly. Is there anyway to do this?

I've tried the following but none got it to re.compile(`anyword\(`):

```
pattern = re.compile( bytes( args.p, "utf-8").decode('unicode_escape') ) 
pattern = re.compile( str.encode( args.p ).decode('unicode_escape') )
pattern = re.compile( eval( args.p) )
```

Comment: can you share input string as well ?

Comment: The user may need to escape the backslash when entering it on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two good approaches from responses to a [google page](https://plus.google.com/101601879152225382803/posts/627K5E1DmMj):

**Dhruv Kanojia(Xonshiz)** wrote a [regexEntry.py](https://gist.github.com/Xonshiz/c0eebb2f8dc0b45753090c6515ed2a3a) that uses this:

`pattern = re.compile("{0}".format(user_input))`

and **Evgeniy Lobov** simply uses:

`pattern = re.compile("anyword[(]")`

Both work but Dhruv's approach doesn't require users to add [ ].

Answer (score 0):

I'd reckon that this is is a rather bad approach (escaping on the command line, etc.), but this works:

```
import argparse, re

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--pattern", required = True, help= "regex pattern")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

string = "here is someword hidden"

if re.search(args["pattern"], string):
    print("Found")
```

When calling via `python task.py -p "someword.+"` this yields

```
Found
```